# When implementing Firebase Realtime Database, should I create a contract class?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Since the purpose of a contract class is to maintain a document of all important constants, it seems appropriate. But is it?

Comment: Firebase doesn't imply that you create a contract class. It's up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a common practice to use a contract class. In this class you can add constants that you can use whenever you need in your project.

An example of a constant can be the root of your Firebase database.

```
public static final DatabaseReference ROOT_REF = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

If you for example are using in many parts of your code the users section of your database, you can create also another constant reference:

```
public static final DatabaseReference USERS_REF = ROOT_REF.child("users");
```

Another example would be to add special methods. I'm having in my class for example, a method that helps me escape some special characters that are not allowed to be used in Firebase. Everything that you need to use very often, add it in this contract class.